# Why is a minipage using \textwidth generating an overfull hbox?

Tags: minipage

In the following example, I'm using a `minipage` that should span the entire text area.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\overfullrule}{10pt}

\begin{document} 

before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before
before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before
before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before before

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside
inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside
inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside inside
\end{minipage}

after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after
after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after
after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after after 

\end{document}
```

While this works, it also generates a warning (`Overfull \hbox (10.95003pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--16`).

[image: problem]

There are already numerous answers to similar problems, but none of the solutions I've tried so far seem to apply here. I'm using the `parsnip` option, so I understand that a[dding `\noindent`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64048/21841) before the minipage environment does not change anything. I've tried to [escape virtually any line break using `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156769/21841), to no avail. If I reduce the width of the minipage to `0.97\textwidth`, the warning disappears, but the minipage text is visibly narrower than the rest of the surrounding text. What is causing the warning in this case?

Comment: I think `parskip=full-` is the key here.

Comment: @Manuel It is, but I would never have found the question you related to...

Comment: Oh, and the `parsnip` obviously should have been a `parskip` - stupid autocorrect, but I'm leaving it in, just in case a package author gets hungry...